# MKH 8000 series

Tags: sennheiser, mkh

Has someone information about  problems that recently has the 8000 MKH series ?
I was told that sennheiser has a lot of Microphones with issues these last months…

Thanks!

Michel

Comment: @Jake, I'm planning to buy a couple of sennheiser to build my MS rig, and during my research for a good place to buy them ( and get the best price possible ) I was told that in the last months Sennheiser have had troubles with a lot of Microphones in the series 8000 , it was that bad that they call for the microphones to be "repaired" . I think it was a problem with RF...
I dont have more information for the moment.
Thanks!
M

Answer (score 1):

What issues did you hear about @Michel? The only thing I've discovered through testing and conversations with other 8000 series users is that Sennheiser shoves all the noise into ultrasonic frequencies. So at regular playback speed, your recordings will be extremely quiet. Attempt to slow any of these recordings down and all that noise floor is pitched into an audible range. Hiss city.

Comment: 'anyof thse recordings'? really? do you speak from experience?of course, hiss or noise floor level with any mic or recording is always relative to the primary signal.... so maybe 'hiss city' IF the hiss is actually loud compared to the primary signal, other maybe its more like hiss suburbs, or even hiss negligible

Comment: I certainly agree with @tim.  The only time I ever noticed this on my 8040 was when I jacked up the gain on a quiet recording by something ridiculous like 50 dB (granted, on this test file I didn't crank the pre's high enough to begin with so that was a handicap there - was too low).  At proper conservatively-hot recording levels, of traffic ambience for example, I didn't notice this.  it also depends on the pre's too - just because a recorder can "record" 96k doesn't mean the pre's , internal signal path, or A/D are any good at it.

Comment: While I agree that the MKH range (as a whole) is very quiet and 'hiss city' is a metaphor I would never use. I do agree with Jake's comment on the shift of noise to the +20KHz range, this is a design choice (made possible by the RF circuit) and has some impact on silent sources. Even with a good preamp (SD/Sonosax) this noise is noticeable when pitching down the content. What goes up, most come down. Link to an article explaining the RF design: http://www.ips.org.uk/files/09_Technology_of_RF_Condenser_Mics.pdf